# Reverse Engineer Java code using BOUML

Tags: java, eclipse, reverse-engineering

I've followed all the instructions here [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRp0ARbEdMg)  but I can't seem to find the option to Class diagram but can only find reverse engineer to class view. Can someone pls help me? I'm trying to reverse engineer my java code from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I tried out the reverse engineering video on Youtube and it worked!